# How to remove files modified between particular dates?

Tags: command-line, rm, timestamp

As in the topic: I would like to remove files in a directory that have been modified in a particular date range. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The command `GNU find` is the way to go. For example, to delete all files in the current directory between 1 and 5 august, you can use the following command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt 2011-08-01 ! -newermt 2011-08-06 -delete
```

It is better to execute the command without the `-delete` action, first, to see the listing of interested files (a good substitute could be `-ls` that produce an ls-like listing).

Removing the `-maxdepth 1` specification will traverse all subdirectories, too.

You can also specify hours, for example

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt '2011-08-01 10:01:59' \
                         ! -newermt '2011-08-06 23:01:00' -delete
```

Be warned to not remove single quotes, that protect spaces between date and time.

The character `!` is a negation, it should be read: newer that this date but **not** newer that this other date.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can I also use something to choose hours' range ? And what is the '!' used for ?

Comment: The `!` is a not. In this example: Not newer than 2011-08-06.

Comment: @lordmonkey: see my editing in the answer

Comment: +1. I didn't know -delete predicate. Maybe it's not needed, but I will add `-type f`.

Comment: @Michał Šrajer: good tips for `-type f`, I forget that. The `-delete` is a GNU extensions, I think.

Comment: Edited to add `-type f` as proposed - it's important that examples are not dangerous.