# List files that were changed between a certain datetime

Tags: ls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove files modified between particular dates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57032/how-to-remove-files-modified-between-particular-dates)

How can I list all files recursively in a directory that were changed within a certain timespan?

like between 23.12.2011 and 25.12.2011 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find some_dir -newermt '2011-12-23' -and -not -newermt '2011-12-25'
```

This includes files modified on 2011-12-23 but not files modified on 2011-12-25. Use `2011-12-25 23:59:59` if you want to include files modified on 2011-12-25.